# c# List of derived class

Tags: c#, polymorphism, derived-class, derived-types

I'm developing a C# WinForm application for work, but I'm stuck and I don't know which is the best way to proceed on. Here's a snippet of code

```
class Block()
{
   // generic Block properties
}

class ABlock() : Block
{
    // specific ABlock stuff
}

class BBlock() : Block
{
    // specific BBlock stuff
}


abstract class Algorithm()
{
   // generic Algorithm properties
   abstract List<Block> BlockList // ??
}

class AAlgorithm() : Algorithm
{
    // specific AAlgorithm stuff
    List<ABlock> BlockList // ??
}

class BAlgorithm() : Algorithm
{
    // specific BAlgorithm stuff
    List<ABlock> BlockList // ??
}
```

I think the situation is pretty simple: every derived class of `Algorithm` has it's own derived class of `Block`, but I want to make it generic and accessible from `List<Block> BlockList` in `asbtract class Algorithm`. I think that it's a common situation and I'm sure there is a solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use generics? `abstract class Algorithm<T> where T : Block` and then `class AAlgorithm : Algorithm<ABlock>` etc.

Comment: Looks like a case where the visitor pattern could be applied.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something, but couldn't you make it an abstract property?

```
abstract class Algorithm()
{
   abstract List<Block> BlockList { get; }
}
```

... then when, writing a class that derives from Algorithm, it won't compile unless the BlockList.get is implemented:

```
public class AlgorithmA : Algorithm
{
    public override List<Block> Blocks
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<Block> { new ABlock(), new ABlock() };
        }
    }
}
```

About the only blemish is that, if code within AlgorithmA wants to use the Blocks property, it might need to cast as (ABlock).